# Compare datetime in peewee sql Python

Tags: mysql, datetime, python-3.x, peewee

Apparently, I could not compare the date in the peewee SQL.

```
START_DATE = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0)    
customer_records = Customers.select().\
                    join(Current_Insurers, on=(Customers.current_insurer == Current_Insurers.id)).\
                    switch(Current_Insurers).\
                    join(Insurers, on=(Current_Insurers.insurer == Insurers.id)).\
                    where(Customers.pol_type == "PC" & \
                          Current_Insurers.effective_date ==  START_DATE )
```

Where `Customers`, `Current_Insurers`, `Insurers` are three `class`. The result is always 0 records. But if I removed the `datetime` condition from the sql and compare as follows

```
 customer_records = Customers.select().\
                        join(Current_Insurers, on=(Customers.current_insurer == Current_Insurers.id)).\
                        switch(Current_Insurers).\
                        join(Insurers, on=(Current_Insurers.insurer == Insurers.id)).\
                        where(Customers.pol_type == "PC" 
for r in customer_records:
    if(r.current_insurer.effective_date == START_DATE):
        print(r.policy_id)
```

Surprisingly we can compare now and print out customers.

What do I need to do to add the `datetime` condition in the `peewee` `sql`?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apparently, I could not compare the date in the peewee SQL.

That's completely incorrect. Do you honestly think that the library would be *that* broken??

The problem is Python operator precedence. You need to wrap the equality expressions with parentheses. So you where clause should look like this instead:

```
where((Customers.pol_type == "PC") & \
      (Current_Insurers.effective_date ==  START_DATE))
```

Additionally, it's typically only necessary to call `switch()` when you have multiple joins to a single model.

Put together, your query should be:

```
query = (Customers
         .select()
         .join(Current_Insurers, on=(Customer.current_insurer == Current_Insurers.id))
         .join(Insurers, on=(Current_Insurers.insurer == Insurer.id))
         .where(
             (Customers.pol_type == "PC") &
             (Current_Insurers.effective_date ==  START_DATE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I had the same problem abd subsequently the same question.

The cause of my issue was that mariaDB was stripping the milliseconds when the original insert was done and python/peewee was passing in the milliseconds in the predicate on the later update. Very frustrating.